# ffmpeg drawtext to overlay text repeatedly over the whole video space

Tags: python, ffmpeg, video-processing

I want a specific text like `Hello world` to be spread across multiple rows and over the whole video space/page like this.
[image]

I'm running ffmpeg commands in the python script using bash as a subprocess. Sample code:

> subprocess.run(
> [
> "ffmpeg",
> "-i",
> input_file,
> "-vf",
> f"drawtext=font={font_family}:text={watermark_text}:fontcolor={font_color}:fontsize={font_size}{background_box}:{watermark_position}",
> "-codec:a",
> "copy",
> "-preset",
> encoding_preset,
> f"./watermark/{media_id}.mp4",
> ]
> )

Is there any good way to achieve this?

Comment: Create a small transparent canvas using `color` filter. Draw text, rotate, use tile filter, overlay on video.

Comment: @Gyan - A question regarding transparent canvas, can you create one just with `color` src filter? As you may have seen in my answer to another post, I had to create it via a trio of filters: `color,format=rgba,colorkey`. Is there a better way?

Comment: `color=black@0,format=yuva420p`

Comment: For the text to repeat, do I have to use multiple draw text filters consecutively?

Comment: ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -filter_complex "color=black:100x100,format=yuva444p[c];[c][0]scale2ref[ct][mv];[ct]setsar=1,drawtext=font='Roboto':text='Test Text':fontsize=36:fontcolor=white,split[text][alpha];[text][alpha]alphamerge,rotate=(55*PI/180):ow=rotw(55*PI/180):oh=roth(55*PI/180):c=black@0[txta];[mv][txta]overlay=x='min(0,-H*sin(55*PI/180))+100':y='min(0,W*sin(55*PI/180))+50':shortest=1,tile=8x8" output_video.mp4

Comment: I'm using the above command but instead of creating tiles for the text only it is creating tiles for the whole video

Comment: ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -filter_complex "color=black:100x100,format=yuva444p[c];[c][0]scale2ref[ct][mv];[ct]setsar=1,drawtext=font='Roboto':text='Test Text':fontsize=36:fontcolor=white,split[text][alpha];[text][alpha]alphamerge,rotate=(55*PI/180):ow=rotw(55*PI/180):oh=roth(55*PI/180):c=black@0,tile=8x8[txta];[mv][txta]overlay=x='min(0,-H*sin(55*PI/180))+100':y='min(0,W*sin(55*PI/180))+50':shortest=1" output_video.mp4 --> I then used this but the text appears only once

Comment: @Gyan can you please help me with this

Comment: Tomorrow...........

Comment: Can you kindly look into this @Gyan

Comment: Later today....

Comment: I've removed extra config that I thought was not needed but still getting the same output (the text appears only once.) Updated command: ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -filter_complex "drawtext=font='Roboto':text='Test Text':fontsize=20:fontcolor=white,split[text][alpha];[text][alpha]alphamerge,rotate=(55*PI/180):ow=rotw(55*PI/180):oh=roth(55*PI/180):c=black@0,tile=10x10[txta];[0][txta]overlay=x='min(0,-H*sin(55*PI/180))+100':y='min(0,W*sin(55*PI/180))+50':shortest=1" output_video.mp4

Comment: Can you please look into this @Gyan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your basic template. I assume the input is 720p.

`ffmpeg -i 720p_input -f lavfi -i "color=black@0:s=64x64,format=yuva420p" -filter_complex "[1]trim=end_frame=1,drawtext=font={font_family}:text={watermark_text}:fontcolor={font_color}:fontsize={font_size}{background_box}:{watermark_position},rotate=a={degree}*PI/180:ow=hypot(iw,ih):oh=ow:c=black@0,loop=-1:1:0,tile=15x9,trim=end_frame=1[wm];[0][wm]overlay=0:0" -c:a copy -preset encoding_preset ./watermark/{media_id}.mp4`

`{degree}` should be replaced by rotation angle.
The ultimate size of each text cell is `64 x sqrt(2) = 90 pixels` on each side.
`15x9` is the tiling layout. Adjust this to cover the full input frame.

Comment: I just had to change the 'rotate' filter to this and it worked. Thank you so much! rotate=(30*PI/180):ow=rotw(30*PI/180):oh=roth(30*PI/180)